# Dynamically generated gauge throw "Cannot read property 'getContext' of null" error in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, gauge

There are some SO questions which address this error but in my case I've canvas elements which are being generated dynamically according to the array length. For eg: If api request returns array of 4 objects then 4 gauge are created with id's generated using index in ngFor loop.

Problem here is that typescript code is executed before gauge are created in DOM. I tried using **ngZone** and **ngAfterViewInit** but none really solved problem. Though setTimeout temporarily solves this problem but you never know how much time does a request takes to complete.

I'm generating canvas in ngFor loop like this

```
<div class="col" *ngFor="let item of total_count; let i = 'index'">
     <canvas [attr.id]="'g' + i"  width="150"></canvas>  
</div>
```

And typescript code for generating and assigning configurations is done after response is received by API i.e

```
getDataCount() {
  this.commonService.getDataCount(this.params).subscribe(results => {
  this.total_count= results;
  this.gaugeOptions();
}, err => {
});
}
```

And then gauge is created using gaugeOptions function

```
var opts = {
  angle: 0, // The span of the gauge arc
  lineWidth: 0.24, // The line thickness
  radiusScale: 0.57, // Relative radius
  pointer: {
    length: 0.61, // // Relative to gauge radius
    strokeWidth: 0.02, // The thickness
    color: '#000000' // Fill color
  },
  limitMax: false,
  // If false, max value increases automatically if value > maxValue
  limitMin: false,     // If true, the min value of the gauge will be fixed
  strokeColor: '#E0E0E0',  // to see which ones work best for you
  generateGradient: true,
  highDpiSupport: true,     // High resolution support

};

  if (this.total_count) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.total_count.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        var opts1 = { ...opts, colorStart: '#efb818' };
        var target1 = document.getElementById('g0');
        var gauge1 = new Gauge(target1).setOptions(opts1);
        gauge1.maxValue = this.total_count.membercount;
        gauge1.set(this.membership_count[i].membercount);


      } else if (i == 1) {
        var opts2 = { ...opts, colorStart: '#b1bec5' }
        var target2 = document.getElementById('g1');
        var gauge2 = new Gauge(target2).setOptions(opts2);
        gauge2.maxValue = this.total_count.membercount;
        gauge2.set(this.membership_count[i].membercount);

      }
      //etc upto i = 5 in my usecase
    }
  }
}
```

Problem here is that how can i ensure that gaugeOptions() function is called after DOM(i.e all canvas elements are loaded after api call)

Comment: If you would show more component logic would be more helpful like when you get data. However you could just wait with initizialing gauge till ngAfterViewInit is called, but I don't know where you execute fetching data and where you initialize canvas

Comment: @PatrykBrejdak I've already posted all the code, I get data from "getDataCount" function and then bind it to ngFor loop in DOM. But the problem is that "gaugeOptions" function executes before canvas gets created through ngFor and eventually it throws error.

Comment: I need something like this pseudo code - 
//get notified when canvas is created dynamically
//call gaugeOptions function immediately after DOM have canvas elements

Comment: Well, I mean more specifically when do you call for get data, but the simplest solution would be create special `component` that would hold only `one cavnas` that takes `@Input` of one item from `total_count` then in it's component define `ngAfterViewInit` and inside it you could create `gaugeOptions`, but there is one more problem you should also add another `@Input` since you need index of current iteration becuase you got diffrent options for diffrent index of canvas

Comment: I call "getDataCount" inside ngOnInit lifecycle method, yes gauge can be 1,2,3 or 4 depending on different conditions thats why I'm looping it dynamically

Comment: Then you should go with the method above it's pretty clean and simply solution that should work